# Using the Salesforce Mobile SDK how do I prevent login except for a particular UserId

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, login

I only want one particular user to be able to login, and I want to manage this client side. Ie once the app is installed, and any user logs in for the first time, no other user should be able to log in unless the app is reinstalled. So I'll store the UserId in UserDefaults, but how would I hook into the Oauth or otherwise prevent them logging in with a different UserId? I am developing for native iOS.

Comment: Sounds like you've answered your own question, no? After first login, store something in `NSUserDefaults` as it'll be removed when the app is deleted. Then you allow logins, fetch the current user, and log them out again if they've auth'd as someone else. Not a great user experience, but pretty straightforward.

Comment: I agree, although I have a concern about the brief time between when the login for the new user happens and when I can log them out again... since this is a notification, I'm guessing other method calls may intervene during that time e.g. that may alter state either on the device or issue new requests to salesforce.

Comment: Actually looking at the code now... these are blocks, so I'm assuming will happen immediately on the relevant thread, but maybe still different threads might cause the same issue... hmm

Comment: Even if the SDK is firing off other requests after the user logs in, surely initiating a logout should cancel them? If not, that seems like an oversight in the SDK. And I would be surprised if the SDK was firing your callback blocks off the main thread.

Comment: Good points. I checked. The blocks are executed on the main thread. Thanks